# About Finitely Additive Measure and Countably Measure

Tags: measure-theory

I need help in next question:

Let $m\colon S\rightarrow [0,+\infty]$ finitely additive measure and $m^1\colon S\rightarrow [0,+\infty]$, $S$ is a semi-ring, given by 
$$
m^{1}(B)=\sup\{m(B)\mid B\subset S, B\in \mathcal{A}(S),m(B)<+\infty\}.
$$

Give a example, such that $m^1$ is countably measure but $m$ is not. 
(Ps: $\mathcal{A}(S)$ is the ring generated $S$.)

(Sorry for the mistakes in English, I'm still starting.)